# Clone repository with public key

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, git, putty

I've setup a repository on my linux server. I want to work with it but I don't want to type the password every time I operate with the git. So I need the public/private key authentication.

The problem is that on my host machine I use Windows.

Where do I create the keys? On the host(Windows) or on the server (Linux)?

Another problem I've encountered is that generating the keys on Windows - the public key's extension is `.ppk` (which is SSH2) and on Linux is `.pub` (OpenSSH).  Do I need to convert the key somehow?

Is there any post on the internet that will explain and give a full solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

create the keys on the client/host and put  the pub key in the allowed_keys on the .ssh directory of the user ( you can use openssl to do all of this)
then change the linux ssh config and other necessary files to allow key authentication